# How can i delete products from specified category

Tags: magento-1.9, delete

How can i delete products from specified category by using database or control panel of the magento.

Comment: you want to delete permantly or unassig this products from this category ?

Comment: i need permanently delete from category

Comment: "permanently delete from category" is still not clear. If you want to actually **delete** the products, refer to the linked duplicate. If not, please update the question and be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At magento,Product and category relation has been saved at table  `catalog_category_product_index`.`catalog_category_product` are the main tables.

Basically, `catalog_category_product` is main table.

you need ***to run a delete mysql query by which you can remove that category products.***

**Query:**

> ```
> Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id='YOUR_Cat_ID'
> ```

Comment: How can i add more than one id's